# Why isn't Go 1.6.2 searching vendor/ for packages?

Tags: testing, go, vendor

The structure of the project is:

```
.
├── glide.yaml
├── glide.lock
├── bin
├── pkg
├── src
└── vendor
```

I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) for dependency management, and the `GOPATH` is the location of my project root (absolute path resolving to `.` in the above tree.)

Glide appears to install dependencies correctly, however when attempting to run tests with Go 1.6.2, I don't see it even looking in the `vendor/` folder before failing:

```
GOPATH=/home/charney/myproject go test -i ...
src/myapp/main.go:36:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOROOT)
    /home/charneymyproject/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOPATH)
```

The package it is looking for *is* located at `/home/charneymyproject/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed by moving the `vendor/` folder to inside of the `src/` folder, like:

```
.
├── glide.yaml
├── glide.lock
├── bin
├── pkg
└── src
     └── vendor
```